# Which is the best high performance Jmeter sampler to use for Thrift protocol load testing Beanshell, JSR223 or Java request sampler?

Tags: groovy, jmeter, beanshell, thrift-protocol, jsr223

I have a requirement to load test Thrift protocol with very high user load using JMeter.
I need to know which is the best and most performant JMeter sampler to use out of Beanshell, JSR223 or Java request with high concurrency load?
Appreciate suggestions from industry gurus.
I am open to use other open source tools that can perform the same task.

Thanks,
B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be either [Java Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request) or [JUnit Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JUnit_Request)

Second place will be [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) with [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html) language

And Beanshell will have the worst performance.

More information: [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, it helps.